# Office add in excel- Combination of task pane and udf

Tags: excel, office-js, user-defined-functions, office-addins, excel-addins

i created an office add in for excel (office.js / 365).
The add in creates a sheet with a form. The user put values in the sheet, clicks on the button in the taskpane and the result of the calculations is put into the sheet.

Besides that i want to have a user defined function in the same office add in. The user should have the possibility to choose a cell and put his udf into it.

Is this combination possible? I did not find something in the net.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to define a function using an Excel web add-in. See [Create custom functions in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview) for more information.